# MS Access: list macro from VBA

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have to deal with a few macros (not VBA) in an inherited Access application.

In order to document them, I would like to print or list the actions in those macros, but I am very dissatisfied by the way Access does it.
Therefore I want to make my little piece of code to list the macros, their instructions list and parameters to the debug window or to a text file.
I googled but did not find much on what object(s) contain those macros.

Any clue to put me on track ?

Comment: I found what I needed in the thread mentionned by Remou: by converting the macro to VBA, I have a readable, printable, concise listing of the macro.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the built-in database documenter that will printout all of the macro code in one shot for you?

Go tools->analyze->documentor

This feature allows you to printout all macro code in the whole application

Comment: Yes I did. This is the ugly one I dislike. It shows 4 instructions per page, and the donkeys at M$ haven't figured out since 1992 that EUropeans print on A4 paper.

Comment: And...thanks, Albert. Sorry if my first answer looks a bit rough.